# samba share with option "valid users" is not accessible

Tags: samba

I can connect from windows to linux using a samba share with `guest ok = yes`, like this :

```
[public]
   path = /public
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
```

But, with a share with the `valid users` option, I cannot connect :

```
[data]
   path = /data
   valid users = trogne
   read only = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

All this have been restarted :

```
systemctl restart samba-ad-dc.service 
systemctl restart smbd.service 
systemctl restart nmbd.service
```

And I've run `smbpasswd -a trogne` to set the same password as the linux password.

/data have all permission (`chmod 777 /data`)

I have Windows 10 home.

Comment: Some questions:1. Do you have the same domain defined on windows and samba? 2. Does windows ask for a password when you try to connect?

Comment: 1. I don't use domain. 2. Yes, it ask for password, and I enter \trogne and my password.

Comment: Then you most probably use a workgroup defined as 'MSHOME' or 'WORKGROUP' (check in the control panel under `system`) and make sure you have the same domain defined in samba;  I do not think it is the cause of the problem;  I suggest you to analyze the samba logs on the server machine to have more details.

Comment: Both are WORKGROUP. The only thing that may be relevant in samba logs is this : `[2017/03/03 10:58:43.138185,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2988(check_usershare_stat)
  check_usershare_stat: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/data owned by uid 0 is not a regular file
[2017/03/03 11:02:37.040947,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:2988(check_usershare_stat)
  check_usershare_stat: file /var/lib/samba/usershares/data owned by uid 1000 is not a regular file
`   I've tried changing user from root (uid 0) to trogne (uid 1000). /data have all permission (0777)

Comment: Could you (to make sure) post the result of `sudo pdbedit -L` (command to give a list of Samba users)?

Comment: `sudo pdbedit -L`  : trogne:1000:fisolinux

Comment: Not sure what happens but I would try to add `write list = trogne` to your config file (write list : list of users who have write access to a share).

Comment: thanks for all your help.  Days later, it started to work and I don't why.  It works without `write list = trogne`